# Datatable-Rails fnResizeButtons/aButtons with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

I think this is a rather common question. So I have used twitter bootstrap for the UI and installed datatable-rails gem for datatable. This is essentially what I did.

```
  tradeTable = $("table#create_trades").dataTable(
    "sDom": "T<'row-fluid'>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'p>>"
    "bPaginate": false
        "oTableTools": 
            "aButtons": [ "copy","csv" ]
  )

  $('a[href="#tab3"]').on('show', (e) ->
    oTableTools = TableTools.fnGetInstance('create_trades')
    if ( oTableTools != null && oTableTools.fnResizeRequired() )
      oTableTools.fnResizeButtons()
  )
```

First of all, aButtons does not limit the number of buttons. Secondly, the fnResizeButtons still wouldn't work, after the code, the components (Copy, csv..) still have 0 width and height. I have stepped through the javascript code, and saw that fnResizeRequired() is indeed true, and fnResizeButtons() does get called. What is wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all my efforts, I finally figure out how to do this. For some reason, the datatable-rails gem somehow doesn't perform the resizing properly. But the only thing that needs to be resized is the flash component that is embeded. So what I have done basically is just to resize the components like so:

```
  $('a[href="#tab3"]').one('show', (e) ->
    $('[id^=ToolTables_] embed').each( 
      -> 
        $(this).attr(
          'width': '47px'
          'height': '32px'
        )
    )
  )
```